# how to get part record in java with regex

Tags: java, regex

The returned string is:

```
Return(result="success" dev_id="8116015070006049" total="3"
time="2015-10-04 10:01:25" id="42" name="a" workcode="0" status="0"               authority="0X11" card_src="from_check"
time="2015-10-04 10:09:59" id="42" name="b" workcode="0" status="0" authority="0X11" card_src="from_check"
time="2015-10-04 10:12:36" id="42" name="c" workcode="0" status="0" authority="0X11" card_src="from_check"
)
```

I want to get three records:

```
time="2015-10-04 10:01:25" id="42" name="a"
time="2015-10-04 10:09:59" id="42" name="b"
time="2015-10-04 10:12:36" id="42" name="c"
```

In java I use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\btime=.*(?=workcode=\"0\")");
```

I just got:

```
time="2015-10-04 10:09:59" id="42" name="b"
time="2015-10-04 10:12:36" id="42" name="c"
```

I can not get first one,

why?

Comment: That looks like the return value of a `toString()`. This is for human use when debugging, not for programmatic use. For programmatic access, you should be getting the entries using a getter method.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how you can get what you've posted, but: You must use a non-greedy wildcard after "time=" so as to stop at the next "workcode".

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\btime=.*?(?=workcode=\"0\")");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher( s );
while( mat.find() ){
    System.out.println( mat.group() );
}
```

Prints:

```
time="2015-10-04 10:01:25" id="42" name="a" 
time="2015-10-04 10:09:59" id="42" name="b" 
time="2015-10-04 10:12:36" id="42" name="c"
```